# How to "from module import foo" without importing dependency module?

Tags: python, module, python-import

##### `login.py`

```
import requests

def login():

    base_url = "https://controller/api/aaaLogin.json"
    auth_data = { "aaaUser":{ "attributes":{ "name":username, "pwd":password } } }
    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
    sess = requests.session()
    return sess
```

##### `myapp.py`

```
from login import login
login_session = login()
```

`login()` uses requests module in `login.py`.

`myapp.py` imports only `login()` from `login.py`. However `login_session` is successful, even when I have not imported `requests` module in `myapp.py`.
Need to know how does this work? Are dependencies imported automatically?

Comment: When you import from a module, all the code in the module is executed.

Comment: The only thing that `from XXX import login` does is limit which global variables in the module become global variables in your script. But the module itself has access to all its own global variables.

Comment: Each module imports its own dependencies if they're not already imported elsewhere.

Comment: @barmar and GreenCloakGuy
Thank you for answering. I understood this now